# Tangent line of $f(x)=x^3-x+5$ at $x=2$

Tags: tangent-line

> Find the tangent line of the function : 
>   $$f(x)=x^3-x+5$$
>   at the point $x=2$.

Having difficult time solving this :(
Does anyone know the way to solve this sort of problem??
Wish somebody could help me

Comment: The easiest method would be to differentiate $f(x)$, and substitute $x=2$ into that. Also, did you mean $x=2$? You haven't used $a$ anywhere else.

Comment: Well...do you know how to find the slope of the tangent?

Comment: Do you know calculus? Have you studied the derivative of a function or not yet?

Comment: Not yet sir :(:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT (if you're familiar with elementary differentation) :**

The tangent line at a point $A=(x_0,f(x_0))$ of a differentiable function $f$ at $x=x_0$, is given by :

$$y-f(x_0)=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$

Obviously, the function $f(x) = x^3-x + 5$ is differentiable at $x=2$. Can you now use the formula above to find the tangent line ? What term expresses the slope of it ?

**Alternative (without derivatives) :**

> If $f$ is defined on an open interval that contains $c$ and if the limit 
>   $$\lim_{Δx \to 0} \frac{Δy}{Δx} = \lim_{Δx\to 0} \frac{f(c+Δx) - f(c)}{Δx}=m \space \in \space \mathbb R  $$
>   then the line passing through $(c,f(c))$ with slope $m$ is the tangent line to the graph of $f$ at the point $(c,f(c))$.

Comment: Tangent line = 11x+n ??

Comment: @Oneshox No, where did that $n$ come from ? Please read my post again and apply it. Are you familiar with the derivative $f'(x)$ of a function ?

Comment: Not really sir... :(

Comment: @Oneshox Are you familiar with limits then ? I left you an alternative way above.

Comment: Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

To find the tangent, we need the gradient (rate of change) at $x=2$.

\begin{align}
f(x) & = x^3 - x + 5 \\
f'(x) & = 3x^2 - 1 \\
f'(2) & = 3(2)^2 - 1 \\
& = 11
\end{align}

Hence the gradient of the tangent is $11$. But, we need the y-coords of $f(x)$ at $x=2$.

\begin{align}
f(x) & = x^3 - x + 5 \\
f(2) & = 2^3 - 2 + 5 \\
& = 11 \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{Since}~& t(x) ~\text{passes through (2,11)}\\
t(x) & = mx+c \\
11 & = 11(2)+c \\
c&=-11 \\
\end{align}

Hence the equation of the tangent at $x=2$ is $t(x)=11x-11$.

Comment: OP is not familiar with derivatives at all...